# Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend

I tried to get the value from the input email but when the component is exported it does not appear as a VALUE property, how do I manage to collect what is written in this component exported to this code?
NOTE: I'm creating a design system with STORYBOOK.

```
export const LoginPage: React.FC<LoginPageProps> = ({ }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("")

  return (
    <main className="container">
      <section className="logo">
        <Logo size="small" />
      </section>
      <section className="container-input">
        <div className="input-email">
          <InputEmail> {}</InputEmail>
        </div>
        <div className="input-password">
          <InputPassword />
        </div>
        <Button label="button" onClick={show} backgroundColor="white" />
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Component Struct:

```
export type InputProps = {
  type: 'email' | 'password',
}


export const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ type }) => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("")
  let placeholder: 'Email' | 'Password'


  const handChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputText(e.target.value)
  }

  const show = () => {
    console.log(inputText)
  }

  const getPlaceholder = () => {
    if (type === 'email') {
      return placeholder = 'Email'
    } else {
      return placeholder = 'Password'
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <input type={type}
        name={type}
        id={type}
        onChange={handChange}
        placeholder={getPlaceholder()}
        value={inputText}
        className="input-style"
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

I tried putting it between {}, [] and ().
I tried changing the component.
export property etc.

Comment: You'd usually pass in a callback as a prop and then you'd call the callback from the child component to learn what the value was changed to.

Comment: Can you show this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that you can handle managing data within many components. but in your use case, the simplest approach is callback.

As you might know, you can pass functions as props to the component and call it **inside** of the component.

this is how it can be done:

```
type InputProps = {
    onChange: (value: string) => void
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ onChange }) => {
    ...

    useEffect(() => onChange(value), [value, onChange])

    ...
}
```

now, you can pass a callback function whenever you want to use and `setState` inside it.

```
const Component = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("")

    return <Input onChange={setValue}>
}
```

P.S. For more advanced forms, I suggest you use a library like `formik` or `react-hook-form`